# Pandas: "distribute" column values into multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am a pandas newbie, and I am trying to solve the following problem.

I have a large `DataFrame` (10000 x 28) as follows.

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
  A    B   C    D    E
```

How can I reshape it to look like the following?

```
Col1 Col2 NewColName
  A    B    C
  A    B    D
  A    B    E
```

The first two columns remain the same, and the last three columns get "distributed" over them.

My goal is to take a large `DataFrame` and turn it into "tidy data"

I have tried methods like concat, stack etc. but I feel I'm missing some elegant way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `['Col1, 'Col2]` as `index` and use `.stack()`.

```
df.set_index(['Col1', 'Col2']).stack()

Col1  Col2   
A     B     0    C
            0    D
            0    E
```

Then do `.reset_index()` to format as in your example (you can also add `name='Col'` for the same result as suggested by @jezrael:

```
df.reset_index(-1, drop=True).reset_index(name='Col')

  Col1 Col2  0
0    A    B  C
1    A    B  D
2    A    B  E
```

Comment: Thank you.....I was not familiar with the reset_index (actuall, still not familiar), but it worked!

Comment: Maybe better is add parameter name: `print df.set_index(['Col1', 'Col2']).stack().reset_index(-1, drop=True).reset_index(name='Col')`

Comment: It's quite useful, also look at the `append`, `level`, `drop` etc keywords.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) and [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
print pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Col1','Col2'],value_name='Col').drop('variable', axis=1)
  Col1 Col2 Col
0    A    B   C
1    A    B   D
2    A    B   E
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [58]: %timeit pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Col1','Col2'],value_name='Col').drop('variable', axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.48 ms per loop

In [59]: %timeit df.set_index(['Col1', 'Col2']).stack().reset_index(-1, drop=True).reset_index(name='Col')
100 loops, best of 3: 3.83 ms per loop
```

Comment: And a little faster :) Thank you for upvoting. Nice day.